# Calculate Bootstrap Confidence Intervals in R with Point Estimates from Another Program

Tags: r

I have used an special program for species distribution modeling to create 100 estimates of niche breadth. The important part here is that the data is generated before being entered into R.

With these niche breadth estimates, I would like to get the confidence interval around the mean niche breadth value.

I have seen the boot and bootobject functions, but it seems to me that you are to generate your bootstrapped values using a function, which is not necessary, I think.

Please share any suggestions for getting CIs for this data.

Comment: `quantile(niche_estimates,c(0.025,0.975))` ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a question about statistics more than programming. But it strikes me that bootstrap CIs require drawing bootstrap resamples from your data and reestimating your quantities of interest from the resample, and then examining the distribution of estimates across resamples. How about going the other way, then, from R to your species program? Generate resamples in R, and iterate over them in your other program.

Where to resample from your data, maybe:

```
d = cars
resamples = lapply(1:1000, function(b) {
    d_resample = d[sample(1:nrow(d), nrow(d), replace = TRUE), ]
    d_resample$boot = b
    d_resample
})

stacked = dplyr::bind_rows(resamples)
```

Then subset by the boot variable in your other program.